# Conditions under which a row-stochastic Markov matrix has positive eigenvalues

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, stochastic-matrices, nonnegative-matrices

Let $A \in \mathbb{R}_+^{n\times n}$ be the adjacency matrix of a weighted directed graph, i.e., $A$ is nonsymmetric and with nonnegative entries. Let $M = D^{-1}A$ be the row-stochastic Markov matrix associated with the graph, hence $D$ is the diagonal matrix whose elements are the row-sums of $A$.

I know that from the Perron-Frobenius theorem the eigenvalues $\lambda$ of $M$ are contained within a unit disk centered in 0, and that particularly $\lambda_1 = 1$ where $\lambda_1 > |\lambda_2| > \cdots > |\lambda_n|$.

I was wondering if there were any conditions **on $A$** that allow to bound the eigenvalues s.t. their real part is nonnegative, i.e., $\Re(\lambda_n) \geq 0$.

One sufficient, but not necessary condition is that the symmetric part of $A$ is positive semidefinite, i.e., $\lambda(A+A^T) \geq 0$. Are there other conditions of this type and/or sufficient and necessary conditions that can be stated in terms e.g. of the eigenvalues of $A$ or its entries?

Comment: [Hurwitz matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hurwitz_matrix).

Comment: The Hurwitz stability criterion applies to matrix $M$, but can it be related to some characteristic of matrix $A$? For instance, $M$ can be Hurwitz-stable even if $A$ isn't.

Comment: A small remark: the inequalities $\lambda_1 \ge |\lambda_2| \ge \dots \ge |\lambda_n|$ need not be strict, in general.

Comment: All eigenvalues of a real matrix $B$ have negative real values iff a matrix equation $B^tX+XB=-I$ has a solution $X$ which is a matrix of coefficients of a positively definite quadratic form. This is Theorem 3’ from  Chapter XIV, $\S$5 of  "The theory of matrices" by F. R. Gantmacher. There are also translations (of some edition) “Matrix theory”, **1**  (1959) and “The theory of matrices” **1**, (1977) published by Chelsea.